# Many upvotes to a blatantly incorrect answer: can we solve this situation?

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

A question asks, Nov 9 2010:

> I want the input data be saved always with the FIRST LETTER IN CAPITAL.
>   Example:
>
> ```
> "red house" --> "Red house"
> ```

An answer gives, Apr 28 2016 (roughly 5.5 years later):

> The right way is:
>
> ```
> ToTitleCase(word.ToLower())
> ```

Which actually produces the wrong capitalization (look at the second word):

```
"red house" --> "Red House"
```

So it's wrong, it's not providing the right tool for the job. Yet, the answer gets **117 upvotes** (and some downvotes too, but way less).

I checked the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4135317/timeline) and I didn't notice any merge. And I can't imagine that downvoting has any hope to counter-balance the upvotes. It also affects some other answers.

**Is there a way to solve this situation?** For instance, could we split the question in two?:

- one original question (how to capitalize the *first* word) keeping the correct answers
- one altered question (how to capitalize *all* words) that would inherit the other answers

Comment: Mark it as a duplicate of a question about how to capitalize the first word. I'm sure it's been asked again, and again, and again...

Comment: If there are loads of upvotes, then people are finding it useful. Probably, people want to do the second thing but don't read the question thoroughly. So marking the question as a duplicate would be good, that way the people who want that answer find it here, and people who want the answer to the actual question can find it ima  duplicate.

Comment: @DavyM, Alternatively, they *think* it's useful, until they notice a bug in their code days, months or years down the line. By which time they forgot how they got the code in the first place. I've editted the post, in a way I do not believe conflicts with the author's intent. The author is free to roll back if they wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrong answers are often upvoted over time. We can only hypothesise the reasons. I have two theories:

1. Users test a solution only for specific cases. For example, the answer you highlight is correct for one-word strings.
2. Users favour solutions they understand and "look correct", even if they are wrong. They are less likely to promote correct answers they do not understand.

We can't change user behaviour, but we can use our privileges wisely. With the edit privilege you can, without conflicting with the author's intent, edit the post. I've done it for you by adding this disclaimer:

> **Note:** This will capitalise each word within a string, e.g. "red house" --> "Red House". The solution will also lower-case capitalisation within words, e.g. "old McDonald" --> "Old Mcdonald".

Then move on. As an aside, the timings and history of the Q&A are not relevant here. Do what benefits SO with the privileges available to you.

Comment: "*With the edit privilege you can, without conflicting with the author's intent, edit the post.*" I don't know how you can consider an edit that calls the answer out as being wrong can be considered not conflicting with the author's intent.

Comment: @NicolBolas, You can try reading the edit again. It merely says precisely what the method achieves. Without making any comment on intent. But of course you are free to read your own interpretation, and even roll back the edit if you think it didn't help :).

Comment: @NicolBolas unless their intent was to give a wrong answer I don't think adding that note conflicts with their intent.